# Possibility of applying a homomorphic MAC on vectors

Tags: homomorphic-signatures

The basic idea of homomorphic MACs is that a user can use a secret key to generate a set of tags $σ_1 \dots σ_n$ authenticating values $D_1 \dots D_n$ respectively. so, anyone can homomorphically execute a program $P$ over $(σ_1 \dots σ_n)$ to generate a short tag σ that authenticates $m$ as the output of $P(m_1 \dots m_n)$. 
The authentication tag of a message $m \in Z^p$  is a degree-1 polynomial $y(z)$.

Could this tag be generated for message expressed as vector of $n$ scalars?

Comment: Please review your post before hitting the final button, there was a clear mistake in the title. We've got MathJax / $\LaTeX$ support on this site to help you format your questions (take a look at the edits).